# Laravel 6 Seed DB When relation is on 1 table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have one table which it has a column named "parent_id".

```
      Schema::create('yazilars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        .
        .
        .
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('yazilars');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

When I try to seed the db, I get following error. I know the error should be there because I am trying to relate the rows which are not created yet.

The error is:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

My Seeder file;

```
public function run(){
    $json = File::get("database/veriler/yazilar.json");
    $data = json_decode($json);
    foreach ($data as $obj) {
        Yazilar::create(array(
        'id' => $obj->id,
        .
        .
        .
        "yazilar_id" => $obj->yazilar_id
      ));
    }
}
```

Comment: "_because I am trying to relate the rows which are not created yet_" Create the rows to relate to first then

Comment: Also, it would be useful for you to include the seeding process in your post. That will clear out how the error is produced.

Comment: Any idea to do that? @kerbholz

Answer (score 0):

```php
database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php
```

add ur parent seeder above in this DatabaseSeeder.php